# Input field with different unit of measure

Tags: sapui5

I have a model filed in my JSONMOdel. The name of field id `LENGTH_M`  (lenght in meters)

In my app I use (view and **edit**) it into two position (two input https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Input.html)

- 1st input is:

  Length: `________`  (m)

  where user should insert the lenght in meters
- 2nd input is:

  Length: `________`  (mm)

  where user should  insert the lenght in millimeters

I want insert in both case in the model the value 2 (in meters)
How can I do it if I want bind 1st and 2nd input with the same model property `LENGTH_M` ?

DateTimeInput https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.DateTimeInput/properties has a good property `displayFormat`. I can use it to show the property model in different modes. There is something like that in Input component??

I have tried to use formatter but it does not seem to work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You need to use a type in the binding.
Basically a "type" is associated with the 2 ends of the binding, making conversions to and from the model.

You can create your own binding, for instance, you could store the value in milimeters in the model. The meters input would use a custom binding type that displays 1/100 of the value in the model (and stores the value *100 in the model).

[More info](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/07e4b920f5734fd78fdaa236f26236d8.html#loio07e4b920f5734fd78fdaa236f26236d8__section_a5r_sb5_xcb)

---

EDIT:
Here's an example:

```js
sap.ui.model.SimpleType.extend("Company.ui.model.type.LengthMeters", {
    formatValue: function(oValue) {
        return oValue/100;
    },
    parseValue: function(oValue) {
        return oValue*100;
    },
    validateValue: function(oValue) {}
});
```

It would be something like this.
You put this code anywhere, can be a new file and you sap.ui.require() it, or it can be in the view if you only use it there.

Comment: Thank you @jumpifzero I have seen Float type https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/91f30dbf6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html but I don't understand where I can insert my conversion formula (*1000) to translate from the model value (in m) to the input value (in mm)

Comment: The documentation example show me only how change the separator or set the number of fracion/no-fraction difgits https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.core.sample.TypeFloat/preview

Comment: This is my example http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=01943943734196915404 but not work

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the formatValue and parseValue of the type. Does it stop? Do you have 404s when loading your project?

Comment: not stop in a breakpoint at `return oValue/100;` and  `return oValue*100;`

Comment: If I set a wrong type in my input (for example Company.ui.model.type.LengthMeters888888888 ) in debug I not have any error....

Comment: Can you put the code in a jsbin or similar? This is very hard for us to see what's going on.